# can we install cloudstack in centOS 32-bit

Tags: centos, package, cloud, yum, apache-cloudstack

I want to install cloudstack on centOS. i have installed centOS6.3 32-bit(i686) in my system.
I want to know if i can install cloudstack on centOS 32-bit.

Waiting for a reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to install cloudstack in 32-bit centos, 64-bit is mandatory bcoz it is similar to setting up a server, but u can have devcloud which is a virtual box based installaion so if u have oracle virtual box then it  is possible. . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See [4.5. Management Server Installation from the Installation Guide](http://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/en-US/Apache_CloudStack/4.1.0/html/Installation_Guide/management-server-install-flow.html)

**However**, it is easier to get started with CloudStack using [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud#DevCloud-Introduction).  DevCloud contains a CloudStack that can run on a single machine.

For more detail, [contact the mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).